# GetWindowText return empty string for another process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I am trying to get Window text of the other MFC application in the loop (I am getting a handle of that other process using ProcessId). But, sometimes I am getting it blank. When I do some activity on that other MFC application I sometimes get the Window text and sometimes it's gone. I tried with GetLastError but it returns 0 when it is GetWindowText return blank. So is there any way I can find out what can be a possible mistake in my application or that other MFC application?

Example code :

```
 HWND hWnd = GetProcessHWND(<processid>); //This is function created to get 
    hWnd using process id
    if (hWnd)
   {
       CWnd *pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hWnd);
       while (pWnd->GetParent())
       {
          pWnd = pWnd->GetParent();
       }
       TCHAR chTitle[MAX_PATH];
       pWnd->GetWindowText(chTitle, MAX_PATH);
   }
```

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code, your question is not yet ready without that. Also, you should add [tag:winapi] when posting it again. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I also thought so, but I read here (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833)  that GetWindowText  does not send WM_GETTEXT for other process. But when tried to send registered message for getting Window Text but I found that when GetWindowText return blank at that time, that registered message also not reach to other application. So what can be the reason? Main thread is hang up?

Answer (score 1):

Does your program run with normal user privileges or with full admin rights? If you cannot get the window text from programs running with full admin rights it might be due to the fact that Microsoft has introduced the "[User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI) message filter](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/C/D/8CD015BB-081B-49C5-A506-9C9B570B8DD2/UIPI.pptx)" with Windows Vista: By default, a process cannot send a window message to another process with a higher integrity level.

If this is the case and you have the source code of the programs that do not give valid results you can use the API [ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilterex) (Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2 and up) to allow selected or [ChangeWindowMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilter) (Windows Vista / Server 2008) to allow all messages from a non privileged program to reach a process that runs with higher privileges.

Comment: This can be issue when GetWindowText always return blank, but in my case sometime I get valid GetWindowText and sometimes not, during both the applications are running. So I think sometimes any of the applications is going in some situation when it not getting or sending window text.

Comment: I want to try another way to get Window Text that other application will send window text periodically to my application. Now your above answer will come in picture. My application (say A) is running as Administrator and that other application (say B) is running normally. Now B will send its Window text periodically to A using PostMessage but now A is not receiving messages from B. Will these APIs ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx or ChangeWindowMessageFilter will be added to A or B? Actually I tried it in both but still the result is same. An example will be a good help.